# How add select dropdown category list to theme options

Tags: function, categories, dropdown

I have custom options theme in functions.php and it is a primary codes . I want to use select option to display all categories list and select one instead insert category ID

```
$themename = "تالار وردپرس";
$shortname = "shortname";
$categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0&orderby=name');
$all_cats = array();
foreach ($categories as $category_item ) {
$all_cats[$category_item->cat_ID] = $category_item->cat_name;
}
array_unshift($all_cats, "انتخاب دسته بندي");
/* ---------------------------------------------------------
تعريف آرايه هاي تنظيمات
----------------------------------------------------------- */
$theme_options = array (
    array( "name" =>" تنظيمات" . $themename,
    "type" => "title"),


        /* ---------------------------------------------------------
    تنظيمات اسلاید
    ----------------------------------------------------------- */
    array( "name" => "تنظیمات اسلاید بالای سایت",
    "type" => "section"),
    array( "type" => "open"),   
    array( "name" => "دسته بندی مطالب اسلاید",
    "desc" => "ابتدا افزونه wp_show_id را نصب کنید سپس آی دی دسته بندی مورد نظر خود را در این بخش که با نام پیشنهادی ما می باشد قرار دهید",
    "id" => $shortname."_catslide",
    "type" => "text",
    "std" => ""),
      array( "type" => "close"),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Code

```
array( "name" => "تنظیمات اسلاید بالای سایت",
    "type" => "section"),
    array( "type" => "open"),   
    array( "name" => "دسته بندی اسلاید شو",
    "desc" => "لطفا یک دسته بندی را برای نمایش مطالب منتخب انتخاب کنید",
    "id" => $shortname."_catslide",
    "type" => "select",
    'section'  => 'general',
    "std" => "",
    'options' => $all_cats),
      array( "type" => "close"),
```